# If a closed ball is positively invariant, does no fixed points on the boundary imply that $\dot{r}=0$ there?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Say $D$ is the closed unit ball centred at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For some dynamical system, say $D$ is positively invariant, and that there are no fixed points on its boundary.

This would mean that, in $(r,\theta)$ co-ordinates, there is no point at which $(\dot{r},\dot{\theta})=(0,0)$ for $r=1$. **Is it true that $\dot{r}=0$ at $r=1$?**

It is clear that $\dot{r}\leq0$ at $r=1$ otherwise some orbits would leave the closed ball, which cannot happen when $D$ is positively invariant.

I also feel like $\dot{r}<0$ cannot be true for any $r=1$ since otherwise it would have to emanate from near a fixed point on the circle (not allowed) or there would be some weird discontinuity. I can't find a way to prove this though.

Comment: For $r=1$ you have $\dot r<0$. In this way once trhe trajectory enters in the ball cannot comes out since if at the boundary the derivative is negative this means that the trajectory is repelled inside as it tries to come out

Comment: @pawel I don't see why this is true? For example the system $\dot{r}=r(1-r^2), \dot{\theta}=1$ where $\dot{r}=0$ at $r=1$ but the closed unit ball is positively invariant

Comment: What about something like $\dot r=r(r-2)$, $\dot \theta=1$? Then $\dot r<0$ (for $0< r < 2$) and the closed disk is forward invariant. But I'm not sure what your doubts in the last paragraph actually refer to, so maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @HansLundmark The wording was a bit poor in my last paragraph, I have updated it now so it is hopefully clearer. I am basically asking that, if we have positive invariance in the closed unit disk (the disk with radius 1), and there are no critical points on the boundary of this disk, is it then true that $\dot{r}=0$ everywhere on this boundary? If it is true, the only obstacle here is that I can't figure out how to show $\dot{r}<0$ cannot hold on the boundary.

Comment: But isn't my example a counterexample to that claim? That is, it *is* possible to have $\dot r < 0$ on the boundary. Just because no orbits can go *out* of a positively invariant set, there is nothing stopping orbits from coming *in* from the outside.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thank you for the counter example!